# How do I number the inputs that I take from the user?

Tags: python

How do I list inputs. I'm writing an program whereby when the user inputs 20 heights of the students, it automatically determines the tallest and shortest height. I want to ask for the Input in this way :

```
Height of Student No.1 =

Height of Student No.2 =
```

```
for x in range(20):
    height = float(input("Height of Student No. = " ))
```

I tried to do this:

```
for x in range(20):
    height = float(input("Height of Student No." , x))
```

But it gave me this error `TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2`

Comment: You get an error because the `input` function does not take the extra magic argument you are wishing it had https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: If you want to collect the inputted values into a list, you need to create a list and add them to it. Here are some results for "create a list" in Python: https://www.pythoncentral.io/lists-in-python-how-to-create-a-list-in-python/ https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-list-in-python-declare-lists-in-python-example/

Comment: Since you're an absolute beginner, here's a piece of advice that will make your life a whole lot easier: _read the documentation!_. Python (and most other programming languages) have _extensive_ documentation that describe their functionality, and nearly all of your questions at this level will be solved by reading the docs. (or at least you'll gain a better understanding of the concepts)

Comment: `input()` doesn't works like `print()` where it accepts comma-separated arguments. Have you learned about string concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, `input()` only takes one argument and you gave it two: you gave it your string `"Height of Student No."` and you gave it `x`.

I think what you want here is to include the value of `x` in your string. This can be accomplished using f-strings like so:

```py
for x in range(1,21):
    height = float(input(f"Height of Student No. {x}"))
```

Putting the `f` at the beginning of the string allows you to put variables inside of `{}` and it will evaluate your string.

That said, your result will just save into `height` and then the next one will save over that, and onward, so you probably want to create a list and append them to it, like so:

```py
my_heights = [] # an empty list
for x in range(1,21):
    height = float(input(f"Height of Student No. {x}"))
    my_heights.append(height)
minimum = min(my_heights)
maximum = max(my_heights)
```

edit: start ranges at 1 instead of at 0, end at 21

Comment: their first code has range(20) and the second has range(500), so wasn't sure... but good call on starting at 1

Comment: `range(1, 20)` iterates 19 times, rather than 20. You were fine before, but should use `{x+1}`

Comment: ahhh, good call again!

Comment: My bad. Its actually 20. Also Thank you for your answer !!! Yes im writing more code as we speak but something you just said just intrigued me. Are you saying that every time i input another height, it gets SAVED OVER the previous one??? That would explain a few other minor confusions I have been facing with my other programs. How do I fix that so it makes a list of something of the inputs

Comment: @Rayyan41-_- - you make an empty list and append each item to it, like I've done in the second example.

Comment: not positive why folks are downvoting it, but i think because the documentation for `input()` talks about what arguments it takes, and that it only takes 1, so the answer to your question of why you were getting an error could be found in that documentation. It is also helpful (for the site, really) if questions are generalizable. It is unlikely that anyone will search for how you phrased the question, but really your question is about "Arguments for input giving error" and "How to include number from loop in a string", or something like that. Generalizing your question is better, usually.